# How to use device portal to share anchors between different HoloLens

Tags: hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I would like to create anchors on one HoloLens and then share it with other HoloLens. I want to know does the device portal support this?

Thank you.

YL

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically, moving anchors between headsets in an offline environment can be done with TryGetAnchorStoreAsync, XRAnchorStore or [XRAnchorTransferBatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.openxr.xranchortransferbatch?view=mixedreality-openxr-plugin-1.4) APIs from  Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR.

There is also a way of exporting/importing maps & anchors from a Hololens through Device Portal as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-device-portal#map-manager)

Comment: I tried to use the map manager of the Device Portal to transfer moving map and anchors between HoloLens, but it does not work. I am not clear about the meaning of the "Upload" and "Import". Does the "Upload" means copy the map from PC to HoloLens and the "Import" means store the anchor in the device into anchor store?

Comment: hi @EnJ what do you refer to as "moving map" ? "To import maps and anchors, select Upload a map file and Upload an anchor file respectively and select a map or anchor file that you've already exported.". 
That means you can upload maps/anchors but those aren't imported unless you chose "Import". Same way, you can Reset System map,anchors but any system map/anchors you've exported, are there for you to download and/or import back to Hololens. 

can you give some more details on what is not working? what do you expect to be the result?

Comment: @CaludiuC_MS, Thanks. I want to use one HoloLens to scan one room and then export the map of this room and then import it to another HoloLens. It looks the map manager does not support this.

Comment: @EnJ I am tracking this internally. I will let you know once I have a confirmation

Comment: @EnJ can yo confirm which build you have on those 2 HoloLens that you are trying to export/import from? also, would you agree to open a Support case by using this link: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/?tabs=Contact-us and pick Mixed reality development? this way, we might need some PII information that we can't be shared here.

Comment: Now I can share map and anchors using device portal. Actually, just first export map and anchor and then install the same app on another HoloLens and then import map and anchor. The order is important, first install app and then import.

Comment: great to hear @EnJ